# Python3.6.3, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, bzip2, bz2

In Linux, CentOS

I download the bzip tar file(`bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz`) and

```
make && make install
```

Then I recompile Python-3.6.3

```
./configure --prefix=/home/gt/Py36
make && make install
```

Then I `import bz2` in `/home/gt/Py36/bin/python3` and get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'
```

Then I

```
cp /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/bz2.so /home/gt/Py36/lib/python3.6/
```

Then I get

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_bz2)
```

when `import bz2`

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't just try `pip3 install bzip2` to install the whole thing for you?

Comment: Mac or linux?..

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it is not a duplicate question.

Comment: I asked you if you have a mac or linux. Can you answer please? Also, did you try `pip` as the user above suggested?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Linux

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I am trying

Comment: Then the linked questions above should address your problem quite well.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The links haven't mention `pip`

Comment: @numbermaniac Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bzip2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for bzip2

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ pip3 meet problem..

Comment: `stackoverflow.com/questions/13915137/how-do-you-assign-bz2-to-an-altinstall-of-python`  save me